# parsing xsd from WSDL using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to build a dictionary using an XSD file which I get from WSDL definition using LINQ to XML.

The nodes which I am trying to parse look something like this

```
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="active" type="xsd:boolean"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="activity_due" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="additional_assignee_list" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="approval" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="approval_history" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="approval_set" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="assigned_to" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="assignment_group" type="xsd:string"/>
```

The link to the XML file is: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97162408/incident.xml

I am only worried about "getKeys".

Basically want to build a dictionary which will give me a key-value pair for "name" and "type" from the above sample node list.

I have got to a point where I can get to the Node list using the code

```
 XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

 XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(url);

 var result = (from elements in xd.Descendants(ns + "element") where elements.Attribute("name").Value.Equals("getKeys") 

                          select elements.Descendants(ns + "sequence")
                          );
```

Now I wanted to build a dictionary in a single function call without writing another routine to parse through the result list using LINQ to XML. Any hints, code samples would be really helpful!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ToDictionary` is your friend here. You can do it all in one statement:

```
var query = xd
    .Descendants(ns + "element")
    .Single(element => (string) element.Attribute("name") == "getKeys")
    .Element(ns + "complexType")
    .Element(ns + "sequence")
    .Elements(ns + "element")
    .ToDictionary(x => (string) x.Attribute("name"),
                  x => (string) x.Attribute("type"));
```

Basically the first three lines find the only element with a name of `getKeys`, the next two three lines select the `xsd:element` parts under it (you could just use `Descendants(ns + "element")` if you wanted), and the final call transforms a sequence of elements into a `Dictionary<string, string>`.